# How can I update my server with changed data from ng-grid?

Tags: angularjs

I have coded the following which I copied from an example:

```
   var cellEditableTemplate = "<input style=\"width: 90%\" step=\"any\" type=\"text\" data-ng-class=\"'colt' + col.index\" data-ng-input=\"COL_FIELD\" data-ng-blur=\"updateEntity(col, row)\"/>";

    // Configure ng-grid
    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'myData',
        enableCellEdit: true,
        multiSelect: false,
        columnDefs: [
            { field: 'Id', displayName: 'Id' },
            { field: 'Name', displayName: 'Name', enableCellEdit: true, editableCellTemplate: cellEditableTemplate },
            { field: 'Description', displayName: 'Description', enableCellEdit: true, editableCellTemplate: cellEditableTemplate }
        ]
    };


    // Update Entity on the server side
    $scope.updateEntity = function (column, row) {
        console.log(row.entity);
        console.log(column.field);
        // code for saving data to the server...
        // row.entity.$update() ... <- the simple case
    }
```

Everything works and the correct data is logged to the console.

Now I need to understand how I can update data on my server. The creator of the example is suggesting

```
row.entity.$update()
```

Can someone help me out. Is this a function that's part of the ng-grid and if not then how could I implement the $update to change data on my server through http?

Comment: I've got 

Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngModel&p1=ngInput
    at Error (native)

no ng-model ?

Comment: if i add ng-model='COL_FIELD' app runs correctly, but updateEntity is never called.
angular 1.2.26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you know the column, the row, and the new value, you can use $http or $resource or even jQuery.ajax to update your model.